# Unit testing a method which Posts and Deletes by selection C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, post, select, model-view-controller

I have this method which selects one row of a table and copies it to the another table and then it just deletes it from the first one. The problem is that how can I unit test it because it executes two methods (Post and Delete) at the same time.

**Here is the method:**

```
public ActionResult Pay(int id, Car car)
    {
        try
        {
            using (BookCarDBEntities db = new BookCarDBEntities())
            {

                var carToDelete = db.Cars.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
                var book = CreateNewBooking(carToDelete);
                db.Bookings.Add(book);



                db.Cars.Remove(carToDelete);

                db.SaveChanges();


                return RedirectToAction("ListBookings", "Home");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return View(ex + "error");
        }
    }

    private Booking CreateNewBooking(Car car)
    {
        var bookingCreated = new Booking
        {
            id = car.Id,
            model = car.model,
            make = car.make,
            price = car.price,
            location = car.location
        };

        return bookingCreated;
    }
```

Comment: How you would write test for the method which executes only one method(`Delete` for example)?

Comment: @Fabio is that a rhetorical question?

Comment: No :), if you know how to write test for one method you will be able to write test for method which uses more then one.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter how many external function calls your method to have. To get the values from the method calls in your method (that you wanna unit test), you should mock those methods to return certain responses when called with certain parameters.

You should check [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq4) to learn how to mock methods. Also, I suggest you wrap your methods with an interface (BookCarDBEntities). It is more important to write code to testable rather than writing tests to unmanageable code. Hope this helps.

Comment: thankyou for the reply but can you explain a little bit more in details or by writing some code, that would be much helpful.

Comment: The problem with Stackoverflow is people always want fish rather than learning how to fish. If you had a look the page that I linked in my post you can see all possible examples in the code showcase. Also, writing tests for your program is about simplifiying your code to test and easy to understand. So, I wont be adding any code to my comment unless you struggle with in a particular case.